# Use Google Maps in Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to integrate Google Maps v3 with Fancybox2, but it doesn't quite seems to work.

I have the map initialized here: http://vejstrup.dk.nt15.unoeuro-server.com/da/kort.aspx
Then I will call the map with ajax from a link "Vis adresse på kort" here: http://vejstrup.dk.nt15.unoeuro-server.com/da/kontakt.aspx

Sometimes the map seems to load correct, but zoom controls, map controls, Google logos is missing.

The link look like this:

```
<a href="/da/kort.aspx?alttemplate=map" target="_blank" class="open_ajax fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax">
    Vis adresse på kort
</a>
```

and Fancybox script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/map.js"></script>
<script>
                $(".open_ajax").fancybox({
                    width     : '90%',
                    height    : '90%',
                    fixed: false,
                    autoSize : false,
                    autoCenter : true,
                    afterLoad  :  function() {
                        loadMap();
                    },
                    tpl: { 
                      closeBtn: '<div title="' + fbCloseTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></div>',
                      next: '<a title="' + fbNextTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
                      prev: '<a title="' + fbPrevTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

The map.js: http://vejstrup.dk.nt15.unoeuro-server.com/scripts/map.js

What am I missing to fix this?

Comment: Have you ever fixed this? I'm always getting static map.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `iframe` method? Link to your map page directly like :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://vejstrup.dk.nt15.unoeuro-server.com/da/kort.aspx?alttemplate=map">Open Google Map</a>
```

... **notice** the the special class `fancybox.iframe`. Then your script :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width: '90%',
    height: '90%',
    fixed: false,
    autoSize: false,
    autoCenter: true,
    tpl: {
        closeBtn: '<div title="' + fbCloseTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></div>',
        next: '<a title="' + fbNextTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
        prev: '<a title="' + fbPrevTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
    }
});
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uj2La/)**

Comment: Thanks... it works great. I thought it would work with ajax too, but it seems to give some problems.

As it now is an iframe I also had to add the css in that template to style the infowindow text..

Comment: @downvoter : please leave a comment why you are down-voting or prove my answer is wrong ;)